# play a videojs from a given position

Tags: javascript, video.js

I use videojs as player and I want if I restart the video for the second time to start reading from the last position before leaving it the last time

avant quitter le player je stocke la position

```
whereYouAt = player.currentTime();
var currentTime = localStorage.currentTime;
localStorage.currentTime = whereYouAt;
```

to restart it

```
playFilmVideo=function()
{

    if (player.readyState() < 1) {

        player.one("loadedmetadata", onLoadedMetadata);

    }
    else {
        // metadata already loaded
        onLoadedMetadata(); 

    }
}
function onLoadedMetadata() {

                var weAreAt = localStorage.currentTime;

                    var dri = weAreAt.split(".");
                    var LastTime= dri[0];
                player.currentTime(LastTime);

 }
```

when I launch the application for the first time the player starts reading from the position last.but when I leave the player without leaving the application and relaunch it again it starts reading from the beginning of the video

knowing that localStorage.currentTime  is still recovering the last position

Answer (score 1):

you can set/seek current time of video on load using following snippet.

`myPlayer.currentTime(120);` // 2 minutes into the video

ref - [docs](https://docs.videojs.com/player#currentTime)

Comment: Thank you @AmitBhoyar for your   answer; in fact I have already tested setCurentTime (120) with a static  viariable: and gives me the same problem when I run all the application for the first time the video starts from the second 120 but when I leave the video without leaving the application then I restart the video for the second time it starts from the beginning .I don't understand why setCurentTime runs only the first time

Comment: @rajaa can u share a dummy example with sample url and your code so I can work on it quickly.

Comment: thank you so much; I solved the problem; I just removed  the listner "loadedmetadata" outside the function ready and it worked well, sorry for the late response .

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to remove the fuction readyState() and it worked well:

```
player.on('loadedmetadata', function(msg) {

        player.play();
        onLoadedMetadata();

        });

function onLoadedMetadata() {

                var weAreAt = localStorage.currentTime;

                    var dri = weAreAt.split(".");
                    var LastTime= dri[0];
                player.currentTime(LastTime);

 }
```